# JavaFX-8 Canvas within BorderPane

Tags: javafx-8

I'm pretty new to this whole JavaFX thing, as you can probably tell. This is an issue I ran into recently while playing around with the Canvas node. I've got a BorderPane as my root node, and I'd like to have a Canvas occupy all available space within the center of it. However, I'm having some trouble implementing that exact behavior. Here's the just of what I've been trying:

```
public void start(Stage stage){
    BorderPane root=new BorderPane();
    Canvas canvas=new Canvas(250,250);
    //canvas.widthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
    //canvas.heightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty());
    GraphicsContext gc=canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    new AnimationTimer(){
        @Override
        public void handle(long l){
            double width=canvas.getWidth(),height=canvas.getHeight();
            gc.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            gc.strokeRect(0,0,width,height);
            gc.strokeLine(0,0,width,height);
            gc.strokeLine(0,height,width,0);
        }
    }.start();
    root.setCenter(canvas);
    root.setBottom(new Button("Placeholder"));
    root.setTop(new Button("Placeholder"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();
}
```

Instead of expanding as the Pane does, my Canvas just stays centered within it, retaining its original size. If the two commented lines near the top are re-added, the Canvas grows and shrinks as the Pane does, but without regarding the dimensions of its center (as expected). Is there a way to apply this sort of binding behavior to just the center of the BorderPane, or perhaps another way to do this entirely that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Just found a ***much nicer*** solution today (19.05.2014):

http://fxexperience.com/2014/05/resizable-grid-using-canvas/

So much easier and shorter than mine -.-

---

**Now my original approach**:

I had the same problem as you do.

I found a **really ugly workaround** you can use, but maybe there is another method doing this...

My Workaround:

```
class MyCanvas {

    private Canvas cv;
    private StackPane box;

    public MyCanvas(Stage stg) {
        cv = new Canvas(500, 500);
        box = new StackPane();

        box.getChildren().add(cv);

        //When the Stage size changes, the canvas size becomes resetted
        //but the Hbox expandes automatically to fit the with again
        //and so the canvas become resized to fit the HBox
        stg.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number arg2) {
             resize();
            }
        });

        stg.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number arg2) {
            resize();
            }
        }); 

        box.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number arg2) {
            adapt();
            }
        });

        box.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number arg2) {
            adapt();
            }
        });

        paint();
    }

    private void paint(){
        //Paint something ....
        GraphicsContext ctx = cv.getGraphicsContext2D();

        double w = cv.getWidth();
        double h = cv.getHeight();

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

        ctx.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }

    //Add this HBox to your content pane
    public StackPane getBox() {
        return box;
    }

    public void resize(){
        cv.setWidth(50);
        cv.setHeight(50);
    }

    private void adapt(){
        cv.setHeight(box.getHeight());
        cv.setWidth(box.getWidth());
        paint();
    }
}
```

And in your Main:

```
public class Root extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args){ launch(args); }

    public void start(Stage stg){
        MyCanvas cv = new MyCanvas(stg);
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(pane.getBox());
        stg.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stg.show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you solving your problem.

nZeloT

Comment: Many thanks. I ended up combining our approaches and bound my Canvas' width and height properties to a 'regular' Pane, then added the Canvas to that Pane, which I then set as the center of the original BorderPane.

Comment: I'glad I could help you :)